# Decrease flashdrive capacity?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I have a media player device that can read a USB portable device. I bought a SanDisk Cruzer Blade 64 GB USB drive before I realized that the media player can only read up to 16 GB. I have tried a 16 GB drive and it works with no problem, but when I plugged in my new 64 GB drive it cannot read it, the screen just flashes continuously trying to read it.

I don't want the flash drive to go to waste. I don't need it for anything else, I just need it for the media player. Is there a way that I can shrink the capacity from 64 GB to 16 GB? I know you can do it on an external hard drive using tools like Disk Management on Windows, but how about on a flash drive? I have tried to shrink it using Disk Management but with no success. Any kind of alternative is okay as long as this flash drive doesn't go to waste.

Comment: [EaseUS Partition Master](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/resize-usb-flash-drive-partition-size.html) maybe?

Comment: @stuartd haven't yet tried this. will try later and tell you the result

Comment: @stuartd ive tried EaseUS Partition Master but it seems that the resize option is missing when i select the flash drive. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a YouTube video(sorry i forgot the title of the video and the owner of the video), i have finally found a solution using a windows command-line tools called DISKPART. The steps are actually quite simple. These are the steps as explained in the video:

1. Run cmd.
2. Type DISKPART. Then press enter. This will run diskpart tool
3. Type LIST VOLUME. Then press enter. This will list all volumes available on your PC. [Example of my screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj5KG.png)
4. Type SELECT VOLUME #VOLUME NUMBER#. Then press enter. As you can see from my screenshot, VOLUME 4 is my pendrive. So i typed in SELECT VOLUME 4
5. Lastly, type SHRINK DESIRED=#amount to decrease in MB#. then press enter. In my case, i need to shrink it from 64GB to 16GB (48GB different). so i typed in SHRINK DESIRED=48000
6. Done

Answer (score 0):

[Wan999 answered the question](https://superuser.com/a/1305631/167207), but if you want to increase the size back to normal, follow the steps below. Your drive has to be formatted in the NTFS format before doing this!

1. Run CMD (It might have to be ran as administrator)
2. Type in `DISKPART`
3. Type `LIST VOLUME`
4. Select your volume by entering `SELECT VOLUME #VOLUME NUMBER#`
5. Lastly, type in `EXPAND`. I am not sure how to increase the size by a specific amount, only the max size.